# Multivariable chain rule on quadratic cost function

Tags: vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

Consider the quadratic cost function

$$
J(U) = \tfrac{1}{2}U^HAU+U^HBa-2U^HC b,
$$
where $U\in\ \mathbb{C}^{81}$ is the vector of decision variables and the other matrices ($a$, $b$ are vectors) are constant and of appropriate dimension. This is basically a quadratic cost function. I want to optimize this in MATLAB and provide its gradient $\nabla J_U$. So, if i am not mistaken
$$
\nabla J_U=AU+a^HB^H-2b^HC^H,
$$
note that $A$ is an hermitian matrix. The main issue is that $U$ is an intermediate variable, namely
$$
U =  \text{vec}\ \overline{q}q^\top,
$$
where $\overline{(\cdot)}$ denotes the conjugate, $(\cdot)^H$ the conjugate transpose and $(\cdot)^\top$ the non-conjugate transpose. Furthermore, $U\in\mathbb{C}^{9}$. The gradient $\nabla U_{q_1, \dots, q_9}$ is rather cumbersome, but calculable. My question is, how to connect these results with each other? I am not very good at vector calculus but it is obvious that i require the chain-rule here. But i am not certain how to apply it here.

EDIT
Let me give you the origin of the equation. I start with
$$
\begin{bmatrix}q^HE_1q\\ \vdots \\ q^hE_nq\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\text{vec}\ (E_1)^\top\\ \vdots \\ \text{vec}\ (E_n)^\top\ \end{bmatrix}\text{vec}\ (\overline{q}q^\top)=\Gamma u
$$

$E_i$ is hermitian, hence the left term will always be real. In my scenario, you can never arbitrarily multiply $u$ with a complex scalar, because $u$ follows from $q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convenience, define the vectors
$$\eqalign{
b &= Ba,\qquad c=-2Cb \\
y &= \tfrac{1}{2}Au,\,\quad v = y+b+c \\ 
}$$
and the matrix
$$\eqalign{
V &= {\rm Reshape}(v,9,9) \quad\implies\quad v = {\rm vec}(V) \\
Y &= {\rm Reshape}(y,9,9) \quad\implies\quad y = {\rm vec}(Y) \\
}$$
Let's use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
&A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = {\rm Tr}(B^TA)=B:A \\
&A:BC = B^TA:C = AC^T:B = etc \\
}$$
Then your cost function can be written as
$$\eqalign{
J &= y^Hu + b^Hu + c^Hu \\
  &= (y+b+c)^*:u \\
  &= v^*:u \\
}$$
Calculate the differential of $J$
$$\eqalign{
dJ &= v^*:du + u:dv^* \\
  &= v^*:du + u:\left(\tfrac{1}{2}A^*du^*\right) \\
  &= v^*:du + y:du^* \\
}$$
Next, utilize the relationship with $q$
$$\eqalign{
u &= {\rm vec}(q^*q^T) \\
du &= {\rm vec}(q^*dq^T+dq^*q^T) \\
du^* &= {\rm vec}(q\,dq^H+dq\,q^H) \\
}$$
Substitute this into the differential expression, then calculate the gradient
$$\eqalign{
dJ &= v^*:du + y:du^* \\
 &= {\rm vec}(V^*):{\rm vec}(q^*dq^T+dq^*q^T) 
 + {\rm vec}(Y):{\rm vec}(q\,dq^H+dq\,q^H) \\
 &= V^*:\left(q^*dq^T+dq^*q^T\right) + Y:\left(q\,dq^H+dq\,q^H\right) \\
 &= \left(V^H:dq\,q^H + V^*:dq^*q^T\right)
  + \left(Y^T:dq^*q^T + Y:dq\,q^H\right) \\
&= \left(V^Hq^*:dq + V^*q:dq^*\right) + \left(Y^Tq:dq^* + Yq^*:dq\right)\\
&= \left(V^Hq^*+Yq^*\right):dq + \left(V^*q+Y^Tq\right):dq^* \\
\frac{\partial J}{\partial q} &= V^Hq^* + Yq^*, \qquad
\frac{\partial J}{\partial q^*}= V^*q + Y^Tq \\
}$$
Since $J$ is real, these results implies that $(V,Y)$ are hermitian.

Some comments asked about how the trace/Frobenius product
behaves with vectors.
$$\eqalign{
{\rm Tr}(y^TAx) &= {\rm Tr}((Ax)^Ty)
 &= {\rm Tr}((yx^T)^TA) &= {\rm Tr}(A(yx^T)^T) &= etc \\
y:Ax &= Ax:y &= yx^T:A &= A:yx^T &= etc \\\\
}$$

#### Update

The *Frobenius Inner Product* described on Wikipedia is defined as 
$$\langle A,B\rangle = {\rm Tr}(A^HB)$$
and is different from the product used in this answer which is
$$A:B={\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
The *colon product* has the following extremely useful properties
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \qquad&\big({\rm commutes\,with\,itself}\big) \\
A:B\odot C &= A\odot B:C \qquad&\big({\rm commutes\,with\,Hadamard}\big) \\
}$$
which hold even when the matrices involved are complex. 
The Wikipedia product satisfies neither property.

I find the fact that
$\langle A,B\rangle \ne \langle B,A\rangle$
and trying to remember which matrix gets conjugated to be 
a perpetual source of errors.  
The only nice property of the Wikipedia product is 
$$\|A\|_F^2 = \langle A,A\rangle$$
but this only *fractionally* more succinct than  
$$\|A\|_F^2 = A^*:A$$

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. I have made one mistake though; the matrices $A$ and $B$ are defined as $A=\Gamma^H\Omega\Gamma$ and $B=2\Gamma^H\Omega\Phi$. The multiplication $U\Gamma$ by definition results in a real number; hence the cost function is a real number. On top of that $u$ is defined as $u=\text{vec}(\overline{q}q^\top)$ and not $u=\text{vec}(qq^\top)$. Using $(\cdot)^H$ explicitly instead of $(\cdot)^\top$ is not needed, apologies.

Comment: It doesn't matter what pedigree you give to the $B$ matrix. If you select its value such that $u^HBa$ is real, then I can change the vector **variable** to $u^H=\alpha u^H$ where $\alpha$ is an arbitrary _complex_ scalar. The value $\alpha u^HBa$ will no longer be real.  The quadratic term is fundamentally different, since it contains the product of $\alpha$ with its complex conjugate, so it remains real.

Comment: Ive editted the question to show where the equation comes from and why (i believe) the term is real. Anyways, when $u=\text{vec}\ (\overline{q}q^\top)$, i lose what to do in the last steps. $qdq^\top + dqq^\top$ is just the product rule right? And $d\text{vec}\  X=\text{vec}\ dX$?

Comment: Could you also maybe elaborate on how $d\tfrac{1}{2}Au:u=Au:du$? I am not entirely following that.

Comment: And how do you go from $(V+V^\top):(dq\ q^\top)$ to $(V+V^\top)q:dq$? I cannot find one property of the trace that can be used. Since $dq$ and $q$ are vectors, you cannot use the cyclic property (as it only holds for square matrices). Any property that i try to use, results in $dq^\top$

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. Now I understand that $u$ is not a free vector of parameters but is subject to a complicated constrained. I have updated my answer under the assumption that $J$ is real.

Comment: You sir are amazing, thank you so much !

Comment: @user2501247 Kindly accept his answer as well ;)

Comment: Hm @greg is your derivation entirely correct? With complex matrices, according to Wikipedia $A:B=\text{tr}(A^HB)$, while you claim that $A:B=\text{tr}(A^\top B)$, which would yield different results i believe. Subsequently, i am also not sure that $Y:dq q^H=Yq^*:dq$. Also, i am not sure, while providing the gradient to the optimizer, what to do with $\frac{\partial J}{\partial dq^*}$, but that is a different question.

Comment: I've updated the answer to address the Wikipedia definition. Also your algorithm only needs to update $q$, since that will automatically update $q^*$. Therefore you only need the gradient with respect to $q$. Of course you would work with $q^*$ and its gradient instead, in which case $q$ gets implicitly updated.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough man. Ive checked your derivation and it is indeed correct! Again, thank you sir.